# XSLT - Trimming the I/P - Like CONTINGENT_WORKER-1-23 as CW-1-23

Tags: xml, xslt

Via XSLT,I need to trim few characters in my XML input like when ever I see a contingent worker I need to make it a 7 lengh char...! Like in the below code CONTINGENT_WORKER-1-24 need to be converted as CW-1-24? It is applicable only for contingent employees. Remaining employee ID's should go as is.

I tried few samples nothing seems working exact...Can any body share some of the coding samples

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<entry>
    <id>CONTINGENT_WORKER-1-24</id>
    <fname>john</fname>
    <lname>viett</lname>
</entry>
<entry>
    <id>060786655</id>
    <fname>Mia</fname>
    <lname>Nalco</lname>   
</entry>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this template for this if input text is fixed
<xsl:template match="id">
    <id>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(CONTINGENT_WORKER)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="'CW'"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </id>
</xsl:template>
```